# htaccess rule to redirect from subdomains but keep some files accessible

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .xml .rss
Options Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mysite\.net$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?sitename=%1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Thas how my htaccess files looks like. I want all subdomain.mysite.com to redirect to my index file with the name of the subdomain so i can show the appropriate site. Thats working fine, so far...

My problem is that i now need to access for example www.mysite.com/script.php directly and i am getting a 500 error. htaccess is very confusing to me, how would i achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to read your apache error.log to see what is exact error you get for 500 for `www.mysite.com/script.php` URL

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these 3 lines to your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

So the final rules would look like this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .xml .rss
Options Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.mysite\.net$
RewriteRule .* /index.php?sitename=%1 [L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser however once i added those 3 lines it seems to have lost the %1 variable and i still get error 500 on a direct link to a diferent file.